# How to add a custom control (legend with buttons) to react-leaflet v.4 map?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I would like to add a custom Legend in react-leaflet v4 map, but i can't understand how to do it correctly. I have already read the https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control/ example but it is quite complicated.
Please check the image
[image]
to better understand the issue.

**Map.js (Main map component)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet'
import MapLegendControl from './map/MapLegendControl'; //Custom control i want to add

function Map() {
    return (
        <>
            <MapContainer
                center={[37.983810, 23.727539]}
                zoom={6}
                style={{ height: '100%' }}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
                <MapLegendControl map={map} />
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Custom Control (Legend)**

```
import React from 'react'

function MapLegendControl({ map }) {
    return (
        <div className='leaflet-control leaflet-bar map-legend'>
            <button> Test </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MapLegendControl;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To place the legend in the bottom-left, I included the classes 'leaflet-bottom' and 'leaflet-left' inside the MapLegendControl's div:

```
import React from 'react'

function MapLegendControl({ map }) {
    return (
        <div className='leaflet-bottom leaflet-left leaflet-control leaflet-bar map-legend'>
            <button> Test </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MapLegendControl;
```